# About Dark Souls 2 bonfire ascetic boss spawns

Tags: xbox-360, dark-souls-2

My question and the real reason I viewed this. How many can you use regardless of it changing the difficulty to re spawn a boss? Like Old Iron King in Iron Keep if I wanted to spawn him 10 times could I?

I have used many bonfire ascetic already. However I don't want to waste any past the supposed 8.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could, you do not have any limitations on the amount of times you can use Bonfire Ascetics on a Bonfire, the bosses will keep respawning.

Every Time you use one the Games NewGame+ Counter progresses for the Area you use it in, there is a maximum level of difficulty it can get to after which the amount of dropped Souls from Enemies and the Boss is maxed out ( should be 7 if I remember correctly ) though it won't stop you from using more, it just means the souls a Boss or Enemy Drop will not increase any further.